# Group By with Filemaker

Tags: group-by, filemaker

How can I use Group By with FileMaker? Kind of similar problem like this 
[Filemaker sum by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359976/filemaker-sum-by-group). Can someone explain how to use Summary GetSummary?

Id    |Value

1     |50

1     |50

2     |10

2     |5

1|100
2|15

Comment: To the moderators: I asked which part of the linked answer is not clear to the OP. That is a **question**. Please do not remove it. When the OP answers it, I will know how best to help them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new summary field (ValueSummary) for Value field.
2. Sort the records by ID field.
3. Use GetSummary ( ValueSummary; ID ) to get the summary of a particular ID value.

[image: Screenshot]